# tbody:nth-child selector appears to include thead elements

Tags: html, css

```
table > tbody:nth-child(even) {
   background-color:red;
} 

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Body 1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Body 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's a super simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8c8f9ta/1/

Expected results: The second tbody would have background-color: red.

Actual results: The first tbody has background-color: red.

This seems like a strange one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the [`:nth-child()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) works--it looks at *all* the children elements regardless of the element's type.

Since you want to match based on the element *type*, you are looking for [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymtsfjte/)

```
table > tbody:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: 'Doh. Thanks! Just one of those Mondays.

Answer (score 0):

The count starts at 0, so even actually starts on `tbody[0]` Josh has a better answer, ***all*** children of the table is counted ***but*** the `thead` will not be selected.